# In-lining Thumbnail With Title

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

am an amateur theme developer. Am having some trouble with how to design how the loop will look any help.
i want it to look like the way posts look under treading or latest posts from https://upliftmusicafrica.com

I tried using codes like

```
.float {
   float:left;
}
```

still not working PLEASE HELP

Comment: Please explain your question. If possible share some code snippets in the question.

Comment: i want my sites posts to like those of https://upliftmusicafrica.com #wordpress

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: i wanted to design how posts in the loop will appear, thank for your reply i managed to do it